# Is it possible to get GORM to populate nil values with say an empty slice instead of being just nil?

Tags: javascript, go, go-gorm

I'm currently working on a project and right now I have some basic Javascript

`blah.map(function(lBlah) {});`

`blah` is generated from an ajax request to a database which returns an array of objects (or slice if you prefer)

The only problem is I get a JS error: `cannot read property 'map' of null` this is because if my `one-to-many` association has no associated values at the time, it just makes that field `nil` instead of an empty slice so when I `json.Marshal` it it sends a null value instead of an empty `[]` which would fix all my errors, currently having to range over each `struct` that is returned from the database and check for nil values then `make([]blah, 0)` is annoying and looks messy. Is there an easier way to accomplish this? Is it possible to set a default `json:"default:[]"` or something?

```
// ForumContainer is a table in the database
type ForumContainer struct {
    gorm.Model
    ContainerName string `sql:"not null;unique"`
    AccessLevel   int    `sql:"not null;default:0"`
    MainThreads   []ForumMainThreads
}

// ForumMainThreads is the table in the database
type ForumMainThreads struct {
    gorm.Model
    ForumContainerID int    `sql:"index"`
    ThreadName       string `sql:"not null;unique"`
    Threads          int    `sql:"not null;default:0"`
    Replies          int    `sql:"not null;default:0"`
    AccessLevel      int    `sql:"not null;default:0"`
    Posts            []ForumMainThreadsPosts
}

// ForumMainThreadsPosts is a table in the database
type ForumMainThreadsPosts struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID             int    `sql:"index"`
    ForumMainThreadsID int    `sql:"index"`
    Title              string `sql:"not null;unique"`
    Body               string `sql:"type:text;not null"`
    Sticky             bool   `sql:"not null;default:0"`
    Views              int    `sql:"not null;default:0"`
    ReplyCount         int    `sql:"not null;default:0"`
    Replies            []ForumMainPostsReplies
}

// ForumMainPostsReplies is a table in the database
type ForumMainPostsReplies struct {
    gorm.Model
    ForumMainThreadsPostsID int `sql:"index"`
    UserID                  int `sql:"index"`
    Body                    string
}
```

Querying is accomplished by:

`db.Preload("MainThreads").Find(&forumContainers)`

Comment: Could you add more info? How did you define the models? How are you querying?

Comment: @AbelardoMendoza updated

Comment: Well, I have a similar schema with one-to-many relationships and the slice is coming as an empty slice and is being passed correctly to the frontend as an empty array. Could you try: `fmt.Println(forumContainers.MainThreads)` right after the query `db.Preload("MainThreads").Find(&forumContainers)` is executed. It might also be an older version of the GORM. Which version are you using?

Comment: @AbelardoMendoza I'm using as far as I know, the most recent I just did a `go get` a few hours ago

Comment: I just updated my gorm and tried with the same one-to-many models and I still got the empty slice. Did you try the fmt.Println right after the query?

Comment: @AbelardoMendoza hmm weird it seems to be working now, I wonder if I had changed something and not realized it or what....

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the whole list for check if your filed is nil then replace it with empty slice of your struct like this :

```
for i := range list {
    if list[i].MainThreads== nil {
        list[i].SubCategories = make([]ForumMainThreads, 0)
    }
}
```

and repeat that for all fields that is slice of any type

Comment: You can also use Gorm AfterFind Hook.
See this https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Querying-an-object

Answer (score -1):

Years passed but I still run into this issue and it turns out I forgot call `preload` lol.